# Arc Based Text Alignment in D3

Tags: d3.js, label

I'm trying to create a [Radial Hub and Spoke diagram](http://bl.ocks.org/3169420) (http://bl.ocks.org/3169420) with D3 that uses arcs of a pie to represent relationships to and/or from a node of context.  In other words, I'm trying to create a 360 degree view of a node's relationships.

[image]

In the example above, "Node 1" is in the center.  I can't get the textual node names for related nodes #8 - #18 to align "outside" the wheel.  Would anyone know what the best way is to do so?

The code that I'm using looks as follows...

```
    // Add node names to the arcs, translated to the arc centroid and rotated.
    arcs3.filter(function(d) {
      return d.endAngle - d.startAngle > .2; }).append("svg:text")
        .attr("dy", "5px")
        .attr("angle", function(d) { return angle(d); })
        .attr("text-anchor", function(d) { return angle(d) < 0 ? "start" : "end"; })
        .attr("transform", function(d) { //set text'ss origin to the centroid
           // Make sure to set these before calling arc.centroid
           d.innerRadius = (height/2); // Set Inner Coordinate
           d.outerRadius = (height/2); // Set Outer Coordinate
           return "translate(" + arc3.centroid(d) + ")rotate(" + angle(d) + ")";
         })
        .style("fill", "Black")
        .style("font", "normal 12px Arial")
        .text(function(d) { return d.data.name; });

    // Computes the angle of an arc, converting from radians to degrees.
    function angle(d) {
      var a = (d.startAngle + d.endAngle) * 90 / Math.PI - 90;
      return a > 90 ? a - 180 : a;
    }
```

The issue seems to be that I need to evaluate the X and Y coordinates of where the Node labels are placed.  However, I can't seem to correctly find/access those X and Y values.

Thanks, in advance, for any help you can offer.

My Best,

Frank

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to Ger Hobbelt for this...  In short, the angle function needs to be parameterized:

```
    function angle(d, offset, threshold) {
      var a = (d.startAngle + d.endAngle) * 90 / Math.PI + offset;
      return a > threshold ? a - 180 : a;
    }
```

The complete answer can be found d3.js Google Group: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/d3-js/08KVfNmlhRo

My Best,

Frank